# Why won't bundler install JSON gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I get the following error when attempting to run `cap production deploy`.

```
DEBUG [dc362284]    Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find json-1.8.1.gem for installation
DEBUG [dc362284]    An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
DEBUG [dc362284]    Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

It may be important to note that this deployment was working, than I upgraded to Ruby 2.1.0 to remove an encoding error.  I upgraded locally which worked fine. I ran `rvm install 2.1.0` and `rvm use 2.1.0` then changed my `.ruby-version` file to reflect this Ruby upgrade.

The `bundle install` command works locally, but produces the same above error when I ssh onto the destination server and run this command.

If I run `gem list` I can see this in the list of gems.

```
...
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
json (1.8.1)
less (2.3.2)
...
```

If I try the recommended solution `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` Locally and on the destination server I get the following output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.8.1
Parsing documentation for json-1.8.1
Done installing documentation for json after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

So it appears the gem is installed, right?  Why is this happening? How can I solve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What `bundle show json` gives you?

Comment: Add `gem json, '1.8.1'` to Gemfile

Comment: I have gem json, '1.8.1' in my gemfile already unfortunately

Comment: bundle show json give
/Users/ME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.1

Comment: I needed `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` on my Ubuntu.

Comment: gem 'json', '1.8.1' <--- need single quotes

Answer (score 68, accepted):

So after a half day on this and almost immediately after posting my question I found the answer.  Bundler 1.5.0 has a bug where it doesn't recognize default gems as [referenced here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1806)

The solution was to update to bundler 1.5.1 using `gem install bundler -v '= 1.5.1'`

Comment: Had the same issue even after updating bundler, doing a `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` after updating fixed the error message for me.

Comment: ```gem install json -v '1.8.1'``` followed by ```bundle package``` did the trick for me

Comment: Isn't bundler supposed to install these gems for you? I don't understand why you have to install the gems manually. http://bundler.io/rationale.html I'm using Bundler version 1.7.11

Comment: This did not worked for me, sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev worked , found solution https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253

Comment: I'm using bundler version 1.14.6 and also getting this error

Comment: On MAC `bundle update json` worked it updated to 1.8.6 from 1.8.3

Answer (score 75):

```
$ bundle update json
$ bundle install
```

Comment: This did it for me on Ruby 2.4.0!

Comment: Works for rbenv ruby 2.4.1 too (debian / ubuntu)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Ruby 2.4.0 High Sierra. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too under Ruby version 2.4.2p198. Thanks.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it worked for me while the accepted answer did not.  Like @Robert_T_Taylor, I ran this on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 49):

Run this command then everything will be ok

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Answer (score 41):

if you are in MacOS Sierra and your ruby version is 2.4.0.The ruby version is not compatible with json 1.8.3.

You can try add this line in your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'json', github: 'flori/json', branch: 'v1.8'
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 35):

To solve this problem, simply run:

`bundle update`

It will update the version of your bundler. Then run:

`bundle install`

Your problem will get solve. Solution is well explained **[here](https://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2017/04/install-json-gem.html)**.

Comment: +1 Really helpful and got me unstuck. After `bundle update`, the install worked great. Thank you for the clean solution.

Comment: `bundle update` will update all your gems. `gem update bundler` will update bundler.

Answer (score 20):

I found the solution [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/03/an-error-occurred-while-installing-json.html). There is a problem with json version 1.8.1 and ruby 2.2.3, so install json 1.8.3 version.

```
gem install json -v1.8.3
```

Comment: This worked fantastically for me on OSX, Ubuntu across multiple bad versions of the json gem.  In one case I had to delete the lock file and rebuild from scratch:

    git rm Gemfile.lock
    bundle install

Comment: Worked fine, first of all I delete the `Gemfile.lock` and then just run `bundle install` and that's it.

Answer (score 12):

You should try

```
$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.2'
```

in my case (Ubuntu 14.04) that didn't work directly and I had to do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

and then I could install the gem and continue. Had one more problem that was fixed by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Hoping helps.

Answer (score 9):

If the recommended answer didn't help because you are already using a newer version of bundler. Try the solution that worked for me.

Delete everything inside your vendor folder. 
Add a line to your gemfile

```
gem 'json', '1.8.0'
```

Then run - `bundle update json`.

It seems to be an issue with 1.8.1 so going back to 1.8.0 did the trick for me.

Comment: Worked when upgrading from ruby 2.0.0 to 2.2.4.

Comment: No need to delete everything. "bundle update json" sufficed.

Comment: Using `gem 'json', '1.8.6'` worked for me. You might want to try that.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this error while trying to get a project to run on my local dev box (OSX 10.6), using Sinatra and Postgresql (through activerecord), running on an rvm'd ruby 2.1. I found my answer here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2511

My [exact problem](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2511#issue-25019802) (after the first block of log entries):

> I also get an error when trying to build native extensions for gems

The [answer](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2511#issuecomment-31535930):

> rvm reinstall 2.1.0 --disable-binary

The [explanation](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2511#issuecomment-31545647):

> OSX does not have a package manager so all libraries have to be installed manually by user, this makes it virtually impossible to link the binary dynamically, and as you can see there are problems with the (pseudo)statically linked binary.

For the sake of completeness, I had first forgotten to update rvm (`rvm get head`), which yielded some other errors, but still needed the `--disable-binary` flag once I had done so.

Comment: Get the following error with your solution: "Version '2.1.0' is ambiguous. Cannot select Ruby implementation/version, please be more specific.
Cannot reinstall unknown package ''"

Comment: You might not have ruby 2.1.0, or more than one version installed through rvm.
Run `rvm list`, and you'll see what is your current version. Use the full string (e.g. ruby-2.0.0-p451) instead of the `2.1.0` mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

`bundle update json`. Helped to get through.

Comment: Successfully installed json 1.8.6 (was 1.8.3)

Answer (score 5):

When I tried to install the json gem using `gem install json` separate from just using `bundle install` I got `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`, looking that up I found using

```
    apt-get install ruby-dev
```

did the trick

Answer (score 3):

For OS X make sure you have **coreutils**

```
$ brew install coreutils
$ bundle
```

Comment: Although I got a warning "Warning: coreutils 8.32 is already installed and up-to-date", this   did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in Bundler not recognizing the default gems installed along with ruby 2.x. I still experienced the problem even with the latest version of bundler (1.5.3).

One solution is to simply delete json-1.8.1.gemspec from the default gemspec directory.

```
rm ~/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/specifications/default/json-1.8.1.gemspec
```

After doing this, bundler should have no problem locating the gem. Note that I am using chruby. If you're using some other ruby manager, you'll have to update your path accordingly.

Comment: yup, it's simple to solve a problem with json bundle. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was missing C headers solution was to download it for Xcode, this is the best way.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Bundle was failing to install json -v '1.8.1' and deleting my Gemfile.lock and running bundle again solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the latest version of json:

```
gem install json
```

Then deleted the line json(1.8.1) from the Gemfile.lock and did a

```
bundle install
```

And then the Gemfile.lock file uses json(1.8.3) without erros

Comment: Just running a bundle update solved this issue for me... in other words using a newer JSON gem build.

Answer (score 0):

Switch ruby version from 1.9 to 2.2 with [rvm](https://rvm.io/) did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, some of the answers mentioned earlier were helpful from understanding point of view, but those didn't solve my problem.

So this is what I did to solve issue.

- Modified gemfile.lock to update json (2.0.2) (*Earlier, it was 1.8.3*)
- Check the Bundler version installed (`Bundler -v` command). I had version 1.12.5 installed
- Install bundler version 1.11.2 (using `gem install bundler -v '1.11.2'`)
- Then run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Sierra:

I ran into this error When i used bundler(`v1.15.3`) in Rails(`v4.2`) project.
The solution for me is `gem uninstall bundler -v '1.15.3'` and `gem install bundler -v '1.14.6'`.