# getting error while runnning rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 

`require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In Gemfile:

```
 coffee-rails was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on 
        railties was resolved to 3.2.16, which depends on
          rdoc was resolved to 3.12.2, which depends on
            json
```

Getting this error while running rails s.How to resolve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't bundler install JSON gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095098/why-wont-bundler-install-json-gem)

Comment: You have not installed all gems yet. `bundle install` broke along the way. Re-run `bundle install` and place the full error stack trace here.

Comment: on running gem install json -v '1.8.6'. getting an error:   **ERROR:  Error installing json:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.4 -r ./siteconf20180129-18806-bb4juz.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

**extconf failed, exit code 1**

**Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.4.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out**

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.6/tests/test_json.rb

Answer (score 0):

commenting the content of gemfile and updating ruby and rails to a latest stable version will solve most of the errors. 
for me I reinstalled ruby and rails using the steps provided at:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04