# Ruby on Rails Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `rails s` I get the following error:

> Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources.
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Does anyone know how I fix this?

Here are the contents of my 
[Gemfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaCYO.png).

And my [gemfile.lock](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZU7U5NIikfbNWVUhCUhpa7O9slq7B83/view?usp=sharing).

I'm using Ruby version
`2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Have you tried to run `bundle install`?

Comment: yes i have and it keeps showing the same error

Comment: Can you update your question with the content of your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Done as requested

Comment: gemfile.lock?:)

Comment: and `ruby -v` plz

Comment: provided all the information as requested

Comment: @ManojKarthik *What* error to you get when running `bundle install`? This is the crucial information, and you have not provided it. Also, please do not post screenshots of the files; just post the actual file (as text).

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec rails s`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem update json` and retry 'bundle install'

Comment: after i try the first command it gives me the same error
and update bundler says there are no updates

Comment: @ManojKarthik I updated answer after you had provided gemfile.lock. Plz let me know if updating json helps

Comment: hmm, here is a thread on the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095098/why-wont-bundler-install-json-gem 
Maybe something from there could help